# Count value not showing up in word counter

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a word counter application using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and am not able to display the value of the count variable. Below is my HTML and JS code:

```js
let count = 0;
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function (){
    let str = document.querySelector(".text-area").innerHTML;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if (str.charAt(i) === " "){
            count ++;
        }
    }
    document.querySelector(".stats").innerHTML = count;
});
```

```html
<div class="window">
    <div class="text-area">
        <label>
            <input type="text" id="text-writing-area">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="calculate-section">
    <button type="button" class="submit">Check</button>
</div>
<div class="stats"></div>
```

Kindly point me in the right direction.

Comment: You need to use `.value` to access the textarea content, not `.innerHTML`

Comment: Use `.value` not `.innerHTML`. Besides that, don't use `" "` as a reference for words counting. One could enter multiple spaces and your code will fail. Follow the duplicate link for more suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the above by using `split` to create an array and from that array use the `length` to obtain the number of words? It is the value from the `text input` element that you need to analyse for text content rather than the `innerHTML` of a DIV element.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function (){
    let str = document.querySelector(".text-area input[type='text']").value;
    document.querySelector(".stats").innerHTML = str.split(' ').length;
});
```

```html
<div class="window">
    <div class="text-area">
        <label>
            <input type="text" />
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="calculate-section">
    <button type="button" class="submit">Check</button>
</div>
<div class="stats"></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why do you answer to closed and duplicated question, instead why do you not answer to the "original" question?

Comment: The question was not closed when I answered and it was not immediately obvious that it was a `duplicate`. To that end if one were to look closely at the inherent issue in most questions now asked on this platform then you could likely close each one as a duplicate as more than likely the question has been asked in some form.

Comment: Probably the page was not up to date, he thought that at your level I could also answer these questions. Sorry :)